# How to add object to existing ArrayList? (java)

Tags: java

I somehow cant get my simple program to work..

Here's the code of one class,

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Lamps
{
    private ArrayList<Lamp> manyLamps;

    public Lamps()
    {
        manyLamps = new ArrayList<Lamp>();
    }

    public void addLamp (Lamp newLamp)
    {
        manyLamps.add(newLamp);
    }
}
```

The arraylist pointing at the object "Lamp" in another class.

The code does compile, but when I run the addLamp method I cant enter anything.

It just says error to string, error to int... What am I not getting? Yes im new to Java trying to do an exercise.

Errors:

"Error: Incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Lamp" 
"Error: Incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to Lamp".

Yes I do realize I probably look stupid, but could anyone ELI5?

Thanks for the idea about "null", now at least I can test some things.

Comment: Dude, addLamp receive an `Lamp` object, which is added to the internal `ArrayList` of the class `Lamps`

Comment: It does not say "error to string, error to int" - please copy/paste exactly what "it says"

Comment: "Error: Incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Lamp"
"Error: Incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to Lamp"

Comment: That error cannot be occurring in the code you have shown. Please show your other code.

Comment: `addLamp(Lamp)` excepts `Lamp` instances or `null`, so why do you call it like this `addLamp(123)` or this `addLamp("a string")`? How should that work?

Comment: We need to see the line of code causing the error, which is probably something like what Tom suggested. You need a `new Lamp` somewhere in your code. Talking of new lamps, I must go and look at my Ikea catalogue...

Answer (score 0):

You method requires a `Lamp` argument, thus you should provide a `Lamp` object.

Depending on how your `Lamp` method looks like, your `main` code should do something like:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Lamps ls = new Lamps();
    ls.addLamp(new Lamp());//or provide additional arguments, if required.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send an object of type Lamp when you use the addLamp() method. It seems that you are sending an integer or an string to the addLamp() method

```
Lamp myLamp = new Lamp();
myLamp.addLamp(myLamp);
```